# How to display a custom css animation with jquery and fall back to just show() if not supported?

Tags: jquery, css

I want to initially have an element hidden and trigger a css animation using jquery. If the browser doesn't support css animations I need it to fall back to just using $(element).show().

Here is my fiddle so far

http://jsfiddle.net/SSsVx/30/

```
<div id="submit-logged-out" class="popout">
    foo
</div>

#submit-logged-out {
background: #000;
color: #fff;
    width:80%;
}
    .popout {
        animation: popout 0.25s ease;
        -webkit-animation: popout 0.25s ease;
    }
    @keyframes popout {
        from{transform:scale(0)}
        80%{transform:scale(1.05)}
        to{transform:scale(1)}
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes popout {
        from{-webkit-transform:scale(0)}
        80%{-webkit-transform:scale(1.05)}
        to{-webkit-transform:scale(1)}
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just detect is CSS animations are supported and fallback if dont:

```
if ('animation' in document.body.style) {
    //    Make sure you use all vendor prefixes
    console.log('We have animations')
} else {
    console.log('Fallback')
    $('#submit-logged-out').show()
}
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SSsVx/32/

Comment: Thanks, i'll mark this as correct but I did find a more elegant solution myself.

Comment: This is the right way. In your example ,"$('#SomeDiv').addClass('MyAnimation').show()", if animation is supported (80% chance) you are seriously hurting the browser by running both JS and CSS in paralel.

Comment: Sure it will, .popout can contain visibility: visible; or display

Comment: Is this the right way? http://jsfiddle.net/SSsVx/34/ it needs to be hidden by default

Comment: Sorry, try this for a more complete example http://jsfiddle.net/SSsVx/35/ I have a feeling you can't animate from a hidden state

Comment: Yes you can, you've overcharged the id="submit-logged-out" element and the .popout specificity was lower. Try this http://jsfiddle.net/SSsVx/41/

Answer (score 0):

Ok found a nice solution

```
#SomeDiv{ .... }
.MyAnimation{ .... }

$('#SomeDiv').addClass('MyAnimation').show();
$('#SomeDiv').hide().removeClass('MyAnimation');
```

This way, if the animation isn't supported, it still hides or shows